# как узнать спрятанный Атрибут name для post get запроса

Tags: post, get

На сайте есть текстовое поле с кнопкой, нужно ввести код чтобы пройти дальше.
Как мне узнать name ( Ключ ) для пост запроса.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, нужно узнать `name` текстового поля. Делается это так через `Просмотр кода элемента` или `view-source:website` в браузере Google Chrome при нажатии Правой кнопкой мыши на текстовое поле.

Comment: Там отсутствует name и нетворк не показывает запрос который я отправляю, только который приходит ответный

Comment: Возможно там спрятано в js, но он зашифрован